# android storing api keys in a dedicated class vs strings file

Tags: java, android, string, singleton, api-key

What are the pros and cons of storing app keys for things such as api authentication in a class as static variables

```
public class Keys {

   public static final int APP_KEY = 4848jffj48j89489;

}
```

vs storing them in a strings file

```
<string name="app_key">4848jffj48j89489</string>
```

I can imagine some memory considerations and advantages of storing them in the strings file (only accessing the variables when needed), but I'm not sure if that leaves the keys available for viewing if the APK was decompiled/extracted

Similarly, I'm not sure about all the implications of using static variables, I think they won't take much memory but I'm not sure if they could possibly be garbage collected and return null, or if the keys can be exposed in an APK that was decompiled/extracted

Anyway, maybe I've missed some other things, so any insight is appreciated.

Comment: keys are available for viewing when the apk is decompiled no matter the method you use.

Comment: @njzk2 proguard would help with this though, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the Android Keychain or KeyStore if you're on API 14 or newer. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html

Comment: I am, I do not understand the clear advantages over other methods, can you elaborate?

Comment: If you're concerned about anyone decompiling and getting access to your API keys, then encryption might be warranted. I have not used the Android Keychain/KeyStore, but it looks like it could work for storing API keys with the SecretKeyEntry: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry.html

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the two methods you are asking about work more or less the same. The static variable is a little bit easier to access in my opinion. Garbage collection should not be an issue. In either case, it would be trivial for anyone to open up your apk and take out a key stored in such a way. Using the Android Keychain or Keystore as suggested gives you the benefit of your key being hidden from all but the most determined (Nothing is completely secure, unfortunately) at the expense of some complexity.

Answer (score 0):

String file is used in case you need to translate the string into several languages.
In your case it seems you don't. So the static way is better since you have easier access to it.